# compare 2 dictionaries in python nosetests

Tags: python, nose

Im using python nosetests to write my unittests and have a requirement to compare 2 dictionaries -

Here is my nosetest method and need to know the right way to compare dicts.

```
def test_outputs_processed(self):
        p = Processing(test_data)
        self.result = [
          {'y2': 1423, 'x2': 923,'y1': 1286, 'x1': 277},
          {'y2': 1345, 'x2': 1953,'y1': 1053, 'x1': 1639},
          {'y2': 1651, 'x2': 923, 'y1': 1286, 'x1': 277},
          {'y2': 1913, 'x2': 850, 'y1': 1570, 'x1': 511,}
          ]
        self.assertEqual(p.execute(), self.result)
```

Comment: Is there really no equivalent to unittest's `assertDictEqual`? Or is it good practice to mix methods from different test frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've used in the past. It first checks to see of the set of keys is equal then checks the values, key for key:

```
def equal_dicts(x, y):

    keys_match = set(x.keys()) == set(y.keys())
    vals_match = all([x[k] == y[k] for k in x])

    return keys_match and vals_match
```

Comment: No need to use set() since dict.keys() returns a set-like object that supports set operations, including equality comparison.